# Change URL parameter without redirecting to new URL

Tags: javascript, url, parameters, url-rewriting

I want to know how it is possible to change the URL parameter without a redirection. For example the user clicks on "page 2" which is implemented with pagination, the data is retrieved via ajax, but I want to provide a URL to the user so he could send that page2 with the same results to a friend or whatever.

Searching the web and stackoverflow everyone states that this is NOT possible, it is just possible to change the hash (`parent.location.hash = "whatever value";`).

But HOW is this done at `Airbnb`? When I search for a city, the URL of the result page is this:

```
https://www.airbnb.at/s/london
```

When I click on "page 2" of the pagination, the data is loaded via Ajax and the new URL is this (without redirection):

```
https://www.airbnb.at/s/london?page=2
```

How is that done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will helps you,Try this

```
 <a href="link1.php" rel="tab" class="link">link1</a> |
    <a href="link2.php" rel="tab" class="link">link2</a> |
    <a href="link3.php" rel="tab" class="link">link3</a>
    <script>
$(function(){
    $("a.link").on("click",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();// or return false; 
        window.history.pushState({path:this.href},'',this.href);
    });
 });
    </script>
```

Comment: can't test it now because i'm not at home, but i'm pretty sure this is the right thing, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Probably with `pushState` from History API.
You can read more about that at **[History API](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html)** or **[Manipulating the browser history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)**

Comment: can't test it now because i'm not at home, but i'm pretty sure this is the right thing, thanks :)